# Bug or misconfigured? ASP.NET Core 2.1 firing 404 error on Access Denied

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.1

I am not sure if I found a bug, or if I just messed up the configuration some how.

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Razor website using AzureADB2C authentication, utilizing the new 'pre-packaged' configuration utilities).  When I try to access a page that my test user doesn't have access to, it returns a generic 404 page instead of going to the pre-defined AccessDenied page.

Looking at the browser URL, it is trying to go to:

> https://localhost:44310/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FAbout

But I think it should be:

> https://localhost:44310/***AzureADB2C***/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FAbout
>   (Note: if I manually put this in the browser, it works correctly)

When, you sign out, it takes you to:

> https://localhost:44310/AzureADB2C/Account/SignedOut

Does anyone know if there is a configuration to control this redirect?  Or is this a bug in the new 2.1 Authentication modules? (And if so, any ideas how to work around it until it is fixed?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this to MSFT as a bug and they are looking into it.  But I did figure out a workaround, in case anyone else is getting this same issue.

The issue on MSFT site is: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/301357/microsoftaspnetcoreauthenticationazureadb2cui-acce.html

The workaround is to use the Rewrite Middleware to redirect the call.  Putting the below into the Configure method of your Startup.cs class will handle the issue.

```
        // Workaround for AccessDenied URL error in MSFT code
        RewriteOptions rewrite = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("^Account/AccessDenied(.*)", "AzureADB2C/Account/AccessDenied$1");
        app.UseRewriter(rewrite);
```